# Как установить курсор слева вверху EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

У меня есть "большой" `EditText`, в который будут вводить текст. Курсор изначально устанавливается по середине:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы он был слева вверху?

Код `EditText`:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input_phrases_editText_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background_three"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для позиционирования курсора внутри `EditText` используйте свойство `android:gravity`

В вашем случае (левый верхний угол):

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input_phrases_editText_2"
    ...
    android:gravity="top|left"/>
```