# Как переместить курсор в edittext на первую строку в android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

Я создал plain text, но он длинный, то-есть больше чем на одну строку. Курсор при этом автоматически устанавливается по средине. Как его переместить вверх?[image: что я хочу]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462172/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%85%d1%83-edittext?rq=1

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант программно устанавливать в начало:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_id);
editText.setSelection(0);
```

так же можно задать начальный и конечный индекс элемента и ваш текст (если он будет) будет выбран:

```
editText.setSelection(startPosition, endPosition);
```

это все нужно будет делать уже после того как установите в вашем виджете текст.

Comment: Я использовал setSelection(0); , но ничего не изменилось

Comment: Наверное у вас `EditText` отцентрован по вертикали - проверьте в разметке атрибуты `gravity`(выравнивание текста) и `layout_gravity`(выравнивание самой вью в контейнере), если их нет - добавьте и установите нужное значение